# MockBean in a Spring boot test not getting autowired into the component being tested

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a spring boot Service using an autowired ApplicationEventPublisher:

```
@Service("ILiveOrderHandlerImpl")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ILiveOrderHandlerImpl implements ILiveOrderHandler {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
```

In the spring boot integration test I have specified @MockBean for ApplicationEventPublisher.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {StockTraderApplication.class},
class ILiveOrderHandlerImplTest {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("ILiveOrderHandlerImpl")
  private ILiveOrderHandler liveOrderHandler;

  @MockBean
  ApplicationEventPublisher mockApplicationEventPublisher;
```

While debugging I find that the field isn't mocked but it is the real object (org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext). In the test, the field is the mocked object that fails "verify()" test because it was never autowired. Why does this happen?

Comment: You may need to import the ILiveHandlerImpl on a Configuration class as shown in the Javadoc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Comment: I did this now but still it made no difference: \@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
\@SpringBootTest(classes = {StockTraderApplication.class},)
class ILiveOrderHandlerImplTest {

  \@Configuration
  \@Import(ILiveOrderHandlerImpl.class)
  static class Config {}

  \@MockBean
  ApplicationEventPublisher mockApplicationEventPublisher;

Comment: Also added the qualifier now @Qualifier("ILiveOrderHandlerImpl") below the @MockBean but still no avail.

Comment: Please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)